# textmate open Ruby on Rails partial shortcut

Tags: textmate, ruby-on-rails

Is there a shortcut to open a Ruby on Rails partial in textmate?

```
<%= render :partial => "/arts/menu", :locals => {:art => @art} %>
```

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> does not display partials.

Comment: Technically, this question should not have been migrated to stackoverflow as it involves a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this sheet.](http://www.scribd.com/doc/130869/textmate-rails)

Put your cursor on the partial line, press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and TextMate will open the partial.